# How to dynamically change data in the HTML textarea or text field with php?

Tags: php, html, dynamic-data

I will have a web-application which will use a few complex forms. One form will have examples field on the top and field for user on the bottom. There will be approximately 10 examples. It will be great if i can change text and images without reloading full HTML page.

Form will be based on HTML. Php will do all logic processes. I haven't find information about HTML button - can i use it for this problem or i need just several submit buttons in the form?

How can i implement this using HTML and PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say what you are looking for needs to be done with JavaScript. Have you tried jQuery? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with PHP alone, because it runs server-side and would force you to reload the page.

This is usually a job for [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), which is a technique to make JavaScript-based calls to URLs without reloading the current page.

The jQuery framework has one of the most popular and straightforward [Ajax implementations](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).